# Error in hist$mids: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a density plot and add it a normal curve.

```
histvb <- hist(color$VB,
               probability=TRUE,
               breaks=seq(4000, 16000, by=1000),
               main=NULL,xlab=c("Visible Brigthness"), 
               ylab=("Probability Densities"),cex.lab=1.2) 
vb<-color$VB
xfit<-seq(min(0),max(16000),length=16000) 
yfit<-dnorm(xfit,mean=mean(vb),sd=sd(vb))  
yfit<-yfit*diff(hist$mids[1:2])*length(vb)
lines(xfit, yfit, col="blue",lty=5, lwd=2)
```

When I run these lines, I get the plot with the line and everything seems ok,
but I also get this message

```
yfit <- yfit*diff(hist$mids[1:2])*length(vb)
Error in hist$mids : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I'm concerning about this error message since I don't know what it means..

Comment: It means `hist` is  function and you cannot use "$" right after `hist`.

Answer (score 1):

You mean to do `histvb$mids[1:2]`, not `hist$mids[1:2]`: `histvb` is the result you created in the first line: `hist` is a function that plots histograms. Change your line

```
yfit<-yfit*diff(hist$mids[1:2])*length(vb)
```

to

```
yfit<-yfit*diff(histvb$mids[1:2])*length(vb)
```

Comment: I tried that, but when I run it, it doesn't draw the line at all.
Can't understand why, but I try it again, and same result: histogram OK but no line.

Comment: @Maria: First of all, why aren't you doing `plot(density(vb))`?

Comment: I did it at first, but I preferred the hist with the line to get a visual comparison of my data with the Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I know what you meant,
I just tried this after drawing the hist

>lines(density(vb),col="red") 
and apparently it worked (I'll check it, I'm new at R)